# Rails file_field helper doesn't return anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, attachment, simple-form

I'm using Simple Form. I have a form for creating new items, and a form for editing existing ones. I also have two file fields for every item. Thing that bugs me is that file fields are displayed fine when creating new item, but then they are not generated at all when editing an existing item.

I had this perfectly working in Rails 3.0, now doesn't work on Rails 3.2.1.

The form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @item, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title, :input_html => { :maxlength => 35 } %>
    <%= f.input :description, :input_html => { :maxlength => 450 } %>
    <%= f.input :secure_details, :placeholder => "Serial numbers and other stuff that will remain private", :input_html => { :maxlength => 450 } %>
    <%= f.association :bookmark, :collection => current_user.bookmarks(:order => :position), :include_blank => false %>
    <%= f.input :warranty_until, :as => :string, :input_html => { :id =>'datepicker2' } %>
    <div class="image_attachment">
        <div class="attachment_text">
            Update item photo<br />
            <small>(will replace old one)</small>
        </div>
        <div class="attachment_button">
        <% f.fields_for :assets do |asset| %>
            <%= asset.file_field :photo %>
        <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image_attachment">
        <div class="attachment_text">
            Update receipt<br />
            <small>(will replace old one)</small>
        </div>
        <div class="attachment_button">
        <% f.fields_for :receipts do |receipt| %>
            <%= receipt.file_field :photo %>
        <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <%= f.input :public, :label => "My friends can see this item", :input_html => { :class => "right" } %>
    <%= f.input :giveaway, :label => "Mark as giveaway", :input_html => { :class => "right" } %>
    <div class="margin_r margin_t">
        <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'small_button white right' %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

Basically this part of code doesn't work:

```
<div class="attachment_button">
        <% f.fields_for :assets do |asset| %>
            <%= asset.file_field :photo %>
        <% end %>
</div>
```

The generated HTML is just empty div.

The very same code works when creating a new item, but doesn't work when editing existing one.

Both Assets and Receipts are using Paperclip for storing images. Here is a code for Asset class:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item

    has_attached_file :photo, 
        :styles => {
            :thumb => "80x80#",  
            :small => "150x150>" }
    validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 550.kilobytes
    validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you forgot add this line of code in your Item model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :receipts, :allow_destroy => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true
```

And add '=':

```
<%= f.fields_for :assets do |asset| %>
    <%= asset.file_field :photo %>
<% end %>

<%= f.fields_for :receipts do |receipt| %>
    <%= receipt.file_field :photo %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that missing "=" was it! I sort of assumed that it would work, but seems that in Rails 3.2 the rules are even more strict.